# GLSL Diffuse Shading LWJGL (OpenGL)

Tags: opengl, glsl, lwjgl

After searching, I came up with near nothing. I'm looking for a way to implement diffuse shading in OpenGL with a version of 330 or above (GLSL). My problem is that nothing appears when I load "more complicated" shaders like the diffuse shader below. I can provide my rendering code as well.

**Diffuse.vert**

```
#version 430
layout (location = 0) in vec3 VertexPosition;
layout (location = 1) in vec3 VertexNormal;

out vec3 LightIntensity;

uniform vec4 LightPosition; // Light position in eye coords.
uniform vec3 Kd;            // Diffuse Color
uniform vec3 Ld;            // Diffuse light intensity

uniform mat4 ModelViewMatrix;
uniform mat3 NormalMatrix;
uniform mat4 ProjectionMatrix;
uniform mat4 gl_ModelViewProjectionMatrix;

void main()
{
    vec3 tnorm = normalize(NormalMatrix * VertexNormal);
    vec4 eyeCoords = ModelViewMatrix * vec4(VertexPosition.xyz,1.0);
    vec3 s = normalize(vec3(LightPosition - eyeCoords));

    LightIntensity = Ld * Kd * max(dot(s, tnorm), 0.0);

    gl_Position = gl_ModelViewProjectionMatrix * vec4(VertexPosition.xyz,1.0);
}
```

**Diffuse.frag**

```
#version 430

in vec3 LightIntensity;

layout(location = 0) out vec4 FragColor;

void main()
{
    FragColor = vec4(LightIntensity, 1.0);
}
```

**Render Code**

```
private void Render(boolean UseShader) {
    //Check whether or not to use shader program
    if (Shaders.useShader && UseShader) {
        ARBShaderObjects.glUseProgramObjectARB(Shaders.program);
    }
    //Bind VAO and enable relevant data
    GL30.glBindVertexArray(VBO_OBJ.vaoID);
    //Draw
    GL11.glDrawArrays(GL11.GL_TRIANGLES, 0, VBO_OBJ.totalVertices);
    //Revert to normal
    GL30.glBindVertexArray(0);
    if (Shaders.useShader && UseShader) {
        ARBShaderObjects.glUseProgramObjectARB(0);
    }
}
```

I know that loading shaders works because there is A. No error and B. Simpler shaders work. My guess is that there is an issue with normals or something because I'm having an issue passing normals through to the shader (Java crashes when enabling the 1st index of my VAO) whereas vertices work.

**Simple Shaders Render Correctly, but anything involving lighting seems to fail**

Comment: debug your shader by passing the normal as the end color - if it's all black then you're probably loading them wrong

Comment: Would that be done by binding the index of the normals from my VAO and then using layout(location = 1) in vec3 VertexNormal?

Comment: please show us the code where you render the scène. you would just put LightIntensity = VertexNormal in de Vertex shader to check if the normals loaded correctly.

Comment: I posted the render code, but I think the real issue is getting the model, view, and projection (perspective) matrices. Is there a way to do that without calculations? I would check the OpenGL API, but the site doesn't want to load.